# how to add tensorflow loss functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I can not add these two losses as follows

```
real_loss = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(tf.ones_like(train_images[0]),train_images[0])
fake_loss = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(tf.zeros_like(train_images[0]),train_images[0])
fake_loss+real_loss
```

the error is:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'BinaryCrossentropy' and 'BinaryCrossentropy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add them as multiple losses in `model.compile`

```
model.compile(loss = [loss1,loss2], loss_weights = [l1,l2], ...)
```

This translates to `final_loss = l1*loss1 + l2*loss2`. Just set `l1` and `l2` as 1.